# Region of interest and Data vertices (3D) , matlab

Tags: matlab, figure

i want to have a simple function similar to autocad that allows me to select all lines in 3D with mouse selection.

[image]

in fig I just want to get (x,y,z) of all vetices under selection. Selection function should be just like autocad.

1-mouse click on a line

2- area selection
With cursor info I get only a single point (x,y,z) as shown in figure. It would be nice if I can get all points inside rectangle made by mouse (region of interest can be polygon).

I think the function may look similar to

```
[BW, xi, yi] = roipoly(...)
```

in 3D

```
 [ xi, yi,zi] = roipoly_new(...)
```

Comment: Does "all lines" means all line equations (or lines detected) or just the matrix that all the lines are in (given the boundaries of the mouse click)?

Comment: @ natan just x,y,z of all lines. e.g., for rectangle I will get 8 points.

Comment: Since it is a 2d image, you mean the edges (x0,y0) and (x1,y1) of each line, correct?

Comment: @ natan, no its dxf (3D).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in general you would need something like the following:

[ xi, yi,zi] = roipoly_new(...)

Determine point of view, POV.

Project the ROI outwards from the POV, and test for intersections with all objects with known vertices. This is a ray tracing algorithm, but is analytic for linear problems, so it shouldn't be too hard to implement. First result on matlab central gives this:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/30179

Once you know which objects intersect your rays, the world's your oyster.